# Imagebutton full image, round corners

Tags: android, imagebutton

Well.. I have some ImageButtons in my Android application. I want them to display the full picture. I mean: I want the ImageButton to be JUST the picture, you know?

Ok... so far, so good... I can do it use the property "background".

However I also want the ImageButton to have the corners rounded.

I have the following xml in my layout folder:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
            <stroke android:width="8dip"/>
        <size android:height="8dip"/>    
        </shape>
```

It works perfect when I don't want the picture to fill the WHOLE ImageButton... however when I try to use the picture to use the whole imagebutton... it doesn't show the rounded corners.

Can anyone help me, please?

Bonus question: Also, how can I have a beautiful black line (rounded corners) around the imagebutton?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can suggest you to use ImageView instead of ImageButton and catch its onClick().And you can use this xml file to give it a fine black rounded edges outline to your image:

**image_bg.xml:**(paste this xml file in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#000000" /> 
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#776da8" /> 
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" /> 
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
  </shape>
```

You can use it (in xml file where you have added the image) like:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/image" 
           android:src="@drawable/icon"
           android:background="@drawable/image_bg" />
```

Comment: Nice advice: `ImageView` is better than `ImageButton` is that case. Thx

Answer (score 2):

What is the use of the image button? I'm currently working on a soundboard and i ran into the same issue. Then I realized that it doesn't have to be an "imagebutton" for you to be able to use it like a button. Now i'm just using imageview and then using onclick. As for the aesthetics of the black line i don't know but my images have rounded corners because i brought the images in by creating icons under new/other/android icons. It automatically makes one in each diff size category. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will help you out. You might be able to tweak it slightly to add in black borders when painting the new bitmap.

[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

You can then just attach an onClick handler to the imageview.